# Возможность получать данные из GET или POST по выбору

Tags: php, post, get

Здравствуйте.

Задача: Одним скриптом принимать GET и POST запросы с сторонних сайтов.

```
$tempArr = array_keys($_GET);
foreach($tempArr as $value_key){
    $value_key = checkrequest($value_key);
    $value = checkrequest(urldecode($_GET[''.$value_key.'']));
}
```

Чтобы если в этот скприпт пришли данные с POST он тоже мог их прочитать. По умолчанию GET, а если есть get-параметр metod=post,  то принимал POST.

Comment: Ну, в сделайте в самом начала проверку `if (!empty($_GET['method']))
 { if($_GET['method'] == 'post') { $tempArr = array_keys($_POST); } }else {$tempArr = array_keys($_GET); }`

Comment: Это я понял что так надо сделать, тут проблема с этой строкой $value = checkrequest(urldecode($_GET[''.$value_key.'']));

Comment: Ну, как долбаннутый варинат: задайте в if условии еще и определение для переменной $method равный или $_POST или $_GET  в зависимости от условий

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev так что это за функция, она же пользовательская, покажите что в ней происходит

Comment: это скприт принимает данные (емайл, телефон, имя т.д.) с сайтов это типо API, у меня принимаются данные через GET, мне лениво под один сервис писать скрипт, по-этому хочу чтобы в скрипт можно было отправить данные и POST и GET.

Comment: Эти два значения не взаимоисключающие (как в JavaScript), GET - это то что передаётся в URL, POST - в теле запроса, и могут передаваться одновременно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение этой непосильной для среднего пользователя пхп задачи

```
if (isset($_GET['method']) && $_GET['method'] == 'post') { 
    $src = &$_POST;
} else {
    $src = &$_GET 
}
foreach($src as $key => $value){
    $key = checkrequest($key);
    $value = checkrequest($value);
}
```

Comment: супер! Спасибо! Уж извините, в вроде бы мелких задачах и туплю бывает...

Comment: Мой комментарий был скорее к отвечавшим. Главное здесь - просто привоить гет или пост одной переменной и дальше работать с ней. плюс сам цикл немного упрощен

Answer (score -1):

Есть пара вариантов. Совсем простой: использовать [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.request.php), но в нём помимо POSTа с GETом также лежат куки. Чуть сложнее: проверять [$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php) и принимать решение, юзать дальше только POST или только GET: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { ... } elseif (.. === 'GET') { ..`. В это же условие можете добавить свою проверку на `get-method=post`.

UPD.:

Подмену исходного массива на нужный можно упростить так:

```
$tempArr = !empty($_GET['method']) && $_GET['method'] === 'post'
        ||
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'
    ? $_POST
    : $_GET;
foreach ($tempArr as $key => $value) {
```

Не знаю что у вас внутри `checkrequest`, возможно, придётся поправить и там внутри.

Comment: Вопрос не до конца прочитали, проверять нужно на это - "есть get-параметр metod=post, то принимал POST"

Comment: Проверка гет-параметров - просто ещё одно условие. `if (request == post || get-method = post) { ..`. Сути не меняет.

Comment: Автор явно сказал только при наличии параметра брать POST

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan совершенно верно, чтобы только при наличии параметра method равного post скрипт принимал данные из POST

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan просто не хочу делать копию скприта... хочется не удлиняя скрипт сделать возможным чтение параметров из POST

Answer (score -1):

Я имел в виду что-то в этом роде. Проверять - немного лень.

```
if (!empty($_GET['method'])) {
    if($_GET['method'] == 'post') {
        $tempArr = array_keys($_POST);
        $method = '$_POST';
    }
} else {
    $tempArr = array_keys($_GET);
    $method = '$_GET';
}
foreach($tempArr as $value_key) {
    $string = $method.'['.$value_key.']';
    $value_key = checkrequest($value_key);
    $value = checkrequest(urldecode($string));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Самое короткое решение, просто перед Вашим кодом добавить:

```
if (isset($_GET['method']) && $_GET['method'] == 'post') {     
    $_GET = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
}
```

Comment: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in такая ошибка была на строке $tempArr = array_keys($_GET);